# Old page content not getting disposed before drawing new page content

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I got a problem with my application, developed using Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.1874 (but error was present even before updating the NuGet to this version).
When pushing a new page using
`await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new Views.SessionPage());`
the content of present page is not correctly disposed before drawing the new content.
The problem is really easy, I'll attach a pair of screenshots for better explanation.
**This happens only on iOS physical devices**, while on Android physical devices and emulators I'm not able to reproduce it.
Tested with an iPhone 11 and an iPhone 8 Plus.
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBBzi.png)
[Error screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUYQq.png)

More info on my solution:
Application uses a Tabbed Page as MainPage and as main navigation system, but to get in details of items I use the previously quoted code to push new pages.
A video of the bug can be found here: [Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10YSOBHbQ1eqH69RZhUZvKt4CX88ngNwB/view?usp=sharing).
Edit: you can download a small version of the solution here: [Download solution](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zKUY-Rx0RC10kuuDQix6bJYLmbTn481m/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Could you share the sample so that I can test it on my side directly .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT can you give me an email to add to my GitHub solution? If you prefer I can send a .zip privately.

Comment: I could not provide it because of policy . You could share your sample to github and post the link here .

Comment: Make sure that you had removed all personal info from it(like password, account and personal IP Address) .

Comment: Without seeing your code we would just be guessing however I saw an ever so slightly related issue recently. I found that iOS was much faster and therefore was able to show my new view before my old view had been tidied up (this was actually only because I was tidying up after the new view had been navigated to). It just so happened that Android was slow enough in rendering the new view that the dispose had been called. Basically I had to inform the current view it would be left before leaving it, disposing after was too late for my use case.

Comment: @Bijington same think I thought, but I'd like to avoid workarounds like this just for changing a page. I edited the post adding a download link for the solution.

Comment: @LeviathanCode I can’t decide if it is a workaround or not though. Surely it is better to let the Disposal of the old view happen in the background once the new view has been shown for performance reasons?